# javascript causes an error when dealing with geo location

Tags: javascript, html, prototype, latitude-longitude

So I'm working on a school project by using google maps, and I want to get my position aswell. However, when I run my script: http://pastebin.com/1kU5DSe0

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'lat' of undefined` (on line 15)

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `updateLocation` function, you need to use `this.pos.lat` instead of `GeoManager.pos.lat`:

```
GeoManager.prototype.updateLocation = function (position) {
    this.pos.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.pos.lng = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log(this.pos);
};
```

**EDIT:** I didn't notice this before, but since you're passing in `this.updateLocation` as the call back of `getCurrentPosition`, the context of `this` is different, which means `this.pos.lat` will be

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.updateLocation.bind(this));
```

[Updated JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x4Uf4/1/)

Comment: Then i get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'lat' of undefined

Comment: @user143584, That is the same error. Are you sure you replaced lines 15 and 16 with `this.pos.lat` and `this.pos.lng`? I updated the answer with a JSFiddle example, otherwise, can you post a new pastebin/JSFiddle?

Comment: It's rather weird, i've been changing everything on here to try and make it work

Comment: That latest code works for me, is the JavaScript cached in the browser (I'm not sure how you are running this)? Can you post the problem line numbers or try debugging it through Firebug?

Comment: for some reason some different code just stopped working too..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184024/javascript-all-of-a-sudden-jquery-doesnt-detect-that-my-checkbox-is-checked

It's 4 am here right now, so i'll take a better look at it when i wake up :/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GdM9ZUwR It's still the same way.. It looks like this.updateLocation() isn't called :o

Comment: Can you display how you are calling it? I'm simply doing `new GeoManager().updateLocation({ coords: { latitude: 6, longitude: 3 }});` after pasting your above code. Does it work in a different browser now? Not exactly sure how else to help, what you're posting works fine now.

Comment: No. That would be stupid. this.updateLocation() is being called but "position" is undefined

Comment: That is the correct way to use geoLocation with html5 right? it have worked before so this is kinda weird to me..

Comment: Gotcha, I didn't catch how you were calling this or how the init function was used. I've updated the answer.

Comment: THANK YOU! :) What is the .bind(this) doing?

Comment: Btw, do you know of an way I can use $.Deferred() here? It would be nice to be able to call .done() after the GM.init() so I could use the data once its set, instead of running it too soon or waiting more than necessery

Comment: I tried this: http://pastebin.com/ymjv8qSA But I'm not really skilled with this..

Comment: In short, it passes a scope/context to a function (in this case, the instance of the GeoManager object). You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). I would have to mess with Deferred to figure it out, wouldn't hurt to ask another question if you can't solve that either (since it's different).