# javascript, all of a sudden jquery doesn't detect that my checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

http://pastebin.com/r30Wfvi3

All of a sudden that just stopped working.

```
var showMyLocation = document.createElement('input');
showMyLocation.type = "checkbox";
showMyLocation.className = "checkboxForRange";
showMyLocation.id = "showMyLocation";

$$.children("#showMyLocation").html('<p style="float:left">Vis min posisjon :</p>').append(showMyLocation);

$('#' + showMyLocation.id).change(function () { //location
        console.log("clicked");
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            console.log("y");
            GarageHandler.showPosition();
        } else {
            console.log("n");
            GarageHandler.hidePosition();
        }
    });
```

Here's the output the of the given code:

```
"clicked"
"n",
"clicked"
"n",
"clicked"
"n",
"clicked"
"n",
etc.
```

It should be like:

```
"clicked"
"y",
"clicked"
"n",
"clicked"
"y",
"clicked"
"n",
etc.
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?.

Comment: Please post the code in the question and a live demo to reproduce the problem.

Comment: looks like you have a container and a input field with same id

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2EMDR/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you have an container element with id `showMyLocation` to which you are appending the checkbox, but your checkbox also has the same id which is not valid as id of an element must be unique. In your case so when you register the change handler it is getting registered to the container element not to the checkbox so `this` inside the change handler does not refer the checkbox

You need not have to given an id to the input element to add a change handler for it, you can just use the dom element reference

```
$(showMyLocation).change(function () { //location
    console.log("clicked", this);
    if (this.checked) {
        console.log("y");
        GarageHandler.showPosition();
    } else {
        console.log("n");
        GarageHandler.hidePosition();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2EMDR/), [another way](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2EMDR/3/)

Comment: I LOVE YOU!

I guess i'm just really tired atm :o